# Stop Deeply Nested JSON Array Items/Objects Based on Element Name

Tags: javascript, json

So, I'm relatively new to javascript, and I'm working with a client-side javascript function that inserts JSON results pushed to it from the server.

I would like to stop certain results, independently of that javascript that populating the results.

Usually, if the js was my own, I'd make a guess that I'd use the "splice" function to remove the JSON array entry(ies) that I don't wish to be there, does that sound about right? (I'd got to there through plenty of searching on StartPage and here)

However, I need whatever function I (let's be honest, "you") come up with to trump the embedded results.

Essentially this is normal behaviour:
Webpage > JavaScript Parses JSON for Initial Results
then
Webpage > Scroll > JavaScript Parses JSON for More Results

I'd like to insert something that will stop any JSON items that I don't like. I don't know how to represent that, I'd assume:
Worker in Extension/Add-On > Webpage > etc
I doubt this can be done with CSS ... but that'd be awesome, as I'd just put it in my personal.

If it was splice, I'd have a vague idea (but really I'm flying blind) of how to do it on a base level with splice, but I'm already struggling, and that would deepen for the insanely deeply embedded objects I'm trying to exclude.

---

So. There is *lot* of json data in the section I'm looking at.

I'm purely concentrated on the removing of the array here, but by end goal is two parts:

1. In the ' `contents` ' array in `levelOneB`'s ' `daContentShaper` ' I would
   like to remove any item from the array where in the sub-object '
   `content` ' there is an element called ' `contentTypeA` '. There's another
   object with the label ' `ahThisIsTheBContent` ', which I'd also like gone,
   and that's dotted through the JSON. All other items (TypeB, TypeC, or
   other) must stay.
2. Additionally, within said ' `content` ' object I would like to change any ' `visible` ' values that are " `false` " to " `true` ".

It's definitely possible, it's just working out how to ensure that the rest of the code (which may have similar - not the same - parts elsewhere) isn't affected by my splice of this array.

```
{
    "levelOneA": {
        "levelOneAArr": [ { "name": "me", "age": 1 }, { "name": "you", "age": 2 }, { "name": "them", "age": 3 } ],
        "levelOneAText": "blah"
    },
    "levelOneB": {
        "levelOneBDeepBro": {
            "levelOneBDeepBroTabs": [
                {
                    "levelOneBDeepBroTabsShaper": {
                        "isBlessed": true,
                        "daContent": {
                            "daContentShaper": {
                                "contents": [
                                    {
                                        "contentItem": {
                                            "content": {
                                                "contentTypeA": {
                                                    "bitA": "bitAText",
                                                    "bitB": [
                                                        {
                                                            "bitBText1": "cripes"
                                                        },
                                                        {
                                                            "bitBText1": "crikey"
                                                        },
                                                        {
                                                            "bitBText1": "crimeny"
                                                        }
                                                    ],
                                                    "visible": true
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "extraNonsense": "bingoBlah"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "contentItem": {
                                            "content": {
                                                "ahThisIsTheBContent": {
                                                    "bitA": "bitAText",
                                                    "bitB": [
                                                        {
                                                            "bitBText1": "cripes"
                                                        },
                                                        {
                                                            "bitBText1": "crikey"
                                                        },
                                                        {
                                                            "bitBText1": "crimeny"
                                                        }
                                                    ],
                                                    "visible": false
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "extraNonsense": "bingoBlahBlah"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "contentItem": {
                                            "content": {
                                                "contentTypeB": {
                                                    "bitA": "bitAText",
                                                    "bitB": [
                                                        {
                                                            "bitBText1": "jinkies"
                                                        },
                                                        {
                                                            "bitBText1": "ruh roh"
                                                        },
                                                        {
                                                            "bitBText1": "like, wow"
                                                        }
                                                    ],
                                                    "visible": true
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "extraNonsense": "bingoBlahBlah"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "contentItem": {
                                            "content": {
                                                "contentTypeC": {
                                                    "bitA": "bitAText",
                                                    "bitB": [
                                                        {
                                                            "bitBText1": "cripes"
                                                        },
                                                        {
                                                            "bitBText1": "crikey"
                                                        },
                                                        {
                                                            "bitBText1": "crimeny"
                                                        }
                                                    ],
                                                    "visible": true
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "extraNonsense": "bingoBlahBlahBlah"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ],
                                "myDadIsBetter": "Go Faster Stripes, innit."
                            }
                        },
                        "tabId": "Bro"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "levelOneC": "CAAQhGciEwi0iqD5-ZbwAhUBPvEFHQMKAeo=",
    "levelOneD": {
        "iAmJustHappyToBeNominated": "innit",
        "damnYourWholePopCultureSubsection": "flames abound"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you could solve this using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan)

Note that I used quite a few `**` in the matching. You could write these out exactly, it depends on your requirement

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const data = { levelOneA: { levelOneAArr: [{ name: 'me', age: 1 }, { name: 'you', age: 2 }, { name: 'them', age: 3 }], levelOneAText: 'blah' }, levelOneB: { levelOneBDeepBro: { levelOneBDeepBroTabs: [ { levelOneBDeepBroTabsShaper: { isBlessed: true, daContent: { daContentShaper: { contents: [ { contentItem: { content: { contentTypeA: { bitA: 'bitAText', bitB: [ { bitBText1: 'cripes' }, { bitBText1: 'crikey' }, { bitBText1: 'crimeny' } ], visible: true } }, extraNonsense: 'bingoBlah' } }, { contentItem: { content: { ahThisIsTheBContent: { bitA: 'bitAText', bitB: [ { bitBText1: 'cripes' }, { bitBText1: 'crikey' }, { bitBText1: 'crimeny' } ], visible: false } }, extraNonsense: 'bingoBlahBlah' } }, { contentItem: { content: { contentTypeB: { bitA: 'bitAText', bitB: [ { bitBText1: 'jinkies' }, { bitBText1: 'ruh roh' }, { bitBText1: 'like, wow' } ], visible: false } }, extraNonsense: 'bingoBlahBlah' } }, { contentItem: { content: { contentTypeC: { bitA: 'bitAText', bitB: [ { bitBText1: 'cripes' }, { bitBText1: 'crikey' }, { bitBText1: 'crimeny' } ], visible: false } }, extraNonsense: 'bingoBlahBlahBlah' } } ], myDadIsBetter: 'Go Faster Stripes, innit.' } }, tabId: 'Bro' } } ] } }, levelOneC: 'CAAQhGciEwi0iqD5-ZbwAhUBPvEFHQMKAeo=', levelOneD: { iAmJustHappyToBeNominated: 'innit', damnYourWholePopCultureSubsection: 'flames abound' } };

const logic = {
  'levelOneB.**.daContentShaper.contents[*].*.content.{contentTypeA,ahThisIsTheBContent}': ({ key, parents }) => {
    parents[3].splice(key[key.length - 4], 1);
  },
  'levelOneB.**.daContentShaper.contents.**.visible': ({ value, parent, property }) => {
    if (value === false) {
      parent[property] = true;
    }
  }
};
const modify = objectScan(Object.keys(logic), {
  rtn: 'count',
  filterFn: ({ matchedBy, property, key, value, parent, parents }) => {
    matchedBy.forEach((m) => logic[m]({ property, key, value, parent, parents }));
  }
});

console.log(modify(data));
// => 6

console.log(data);
// => { levelOneA: { levelOneAArr: [ { name: 'me', age: 1 }, { name: 'you', age: 2 }, { name: 'them', age: 3 } ], levelOneAText: 'blah' }, levelOneB: { levelOneBDeepBro: { levelOneBDeepBroTabs: [ { levelOneBDeepBroTabsShaper: { isBlessed: true, daContent: { daContentShaper: { contents: [ { contentItem: { content: { contentTypeB: { bitA: 'bitAText', bitB: [ { bitBText1: 'jinkies' }, { bitBText1: 'ruh roh' }, { bitBText1: 'like, wow' } ], visible: true } }, extraNonsense: 'bingoBlahBlah' } }, { contentItem: { content: { contentTypeC: { bitA: 'bitAText', bitB: [ { bitBText1: 'cripes' }, { bitBText1: 'crikey' }, { bitBText1: 'crimeny' } ], visible: true } }, extraNonsense: 'bingoBlahBlahBlah' } } ], myDadIsBetter: 'Go Faster Stripes, innit.' } }, tabId: 'Bro' } } ] } }, levelOneC: 'CAAQhGciEwi0iqD5-ZbwAhUBPvEFHQMKAeo=', levelOneD: { iAmJustHappyToBeNominated: 'innit', damnYourWholePopCultureSubsection: 'flames abound' } }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@14.3.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)

Comment: Ah, thanks for that, I can't install it, but it sounds like a very useful thing ... I've just recommended it to a colleague!

I'm not sure if I mentioned, but whatever I'm doing will be inserted locally on to a page that's someone else's, via a browser extension/add-on that I may make myself.

Comment: @Eliot Have you considered using Tampermonkey? It would make it easy to use any library and make code changes on the page

Comment: Aha! Thanks, @vicent. I hadn't, and wasn't aware of it, to be honest. I might've found a way to edit the page HTML with CSS, but I'm not sure if that will react to new data that's streamed in through the JSON dumps. If I remember it (and implement it!) I'll come back and share it, but I think the tampermonkey method might be the way to go. Thanks! :-)